# Why do we need to override superclasses' designated initializer

Tags: ios, objective-c

In Aaron Hillegass' Objective-C programming book, he gives a few rules on writing custom init methods.  One of the rules is that "if the designated initializer of your class is different from the designated initializer of its superclass, you must override the superclass' designated initializer so that it calls the new designated initializer (of your new class)"

Why is this mandated.  The only issues I see is that any instance variables in your class will be initialized to null until you explicitly initialize them using their setter.  What is the problem with that?

Comment: Have you gone through this link , it is answered I guess:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669499/override-designated-initializer-of-superclass

Comment: Thanks, yes, it does.  Looks like no consensus!

Answer (score 0):

This is because every initializer for a class must go through the designated initializer for the class, that ensures all common setup occurs in one place. *Even* the superclass' designated initializer should go through your subclass' one, should you make it designated, otherwise setup occurring in your designated initializer could be missed by naïve clients calling into a different initializer.

Comment: "Even the superclass' designated initializer should go through your subclass' one." Don't you mean to say the opposite? As in, the subclass's designated initializer should go through (call) its superclass's designated initializer?

Comment: When overriding the superclass' designated initializer, it should call the subclass' one, when implementing the subclass' designated initializer it and it alone should call the superclass' one.

Answer (score 0):

because it make sure all init for object must call your class designated initializer. If not override designated initializer of its superclass what happen if current class (your custom class) init with one super's initial (designated or convenience) method? your designated initial never called